# Airflow 'no such file or directory'

Tags: linux, ssh, airflow, airflow-2.x

I wish to access another server from my machine using ssh and do some operations there via airflow api. I keep getting errors like 'no such file or directory' even though the directories exist in the server. How do I solve this.

I ran the ssh and cd commands in airflow dag python file using BashOperator. The commands were multiple line but I am not able to get rid of the 'no such file or directory' error.